# ¿Cómo corto la primera letra de cada línea, según condiciones?

Tags: linux, script, unix, procesamiento-de-texto, cut

Estoy intentando realizar un script en linux para poder quedarme con la información de las aplicaciones que me interesan.

Tengo unos nombres de aplicación que vienen precedidos por una E en unos casos y en otros no y lo que necesito es que si la linea empieza por E, me elimine esa E y si es otra letra, me quite pero la última letra de la linea.

tengo un fichero con este formato.

```
A39O
EA60
ED18
ED18
EE67
EE75
EE75
A97O
```

Por comandos sé quitarle la primera letra con un `cut -c 2-4'` y para la mayoría de los casos me sirve pero por ejemplo para los casos A39O y A97O no me sirve porque me queda 39O y 97O.

Necesitaría algo así:

```
A39
A60
D18
D18
E67
E75
E75
A97
```

Estoy empezando en scripting y no sé como puedo hacer un bucle que contemple tantas cosas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer con AWK de la siguiente forma

```
$ awk '{
if (substr($0,1,1) == "E")
  print substr($0,2)
else if (substr($0,1,1) == "A")
  print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)
}' prueba.txt

A39
A60
D18
D18
E67
E75
E75
A97
```

AWK es un <strike>comando</strike> lenguaje de programación que mediante el programa con el mismo nombre (awk) te permite recorrer un fichero línea por línea y escribir un pequeño script para que puedas hacer lo que quieras con esas líneas que lee. En este caso el script hace lo siguiente:

En la primera línea comprobamos si el primer caracter es "E", esto lo hacemos con `substr`. El primer parámetro `$0` es la línea actual que estamos procesando, el segundo es el índice donde empezamos a recortar la cadena, y el tercero el índice donde acabamos de cortar. En este caso empezamos en el primer caracter y acabamos también en el primero por lo que nos saca la primera letra.

Si es E, entonces escribimos del segundo caracter hasta el final, tambien con `substr`.

En el caso de que nos venga una A, lo que hacemos es otro `substr`, pero en este caso, desde el primer caracter, hasta el penúltimo. Esto lo hacemos restando a la longitud de la cadena un caracter.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

EDIT: El redireccionamiento lo tienes que hacer después de la ejecución de AWK, es decir algo así:

```
awk '...' ficheroEntrada.txt >> /home/$USER/definitivo.txt
```

(Donde los puntos suspensivos va el contenido del script)

Comment: Genial!! eso funciona a la perfeccion y parece que ya voy entendiendo el funcionamiento. Una cosa más... Si quisiera redireccionar la salida en lugar de sacarla por pantalla? esto me falla... `           awk '{
               if (substr($1,1,1) == "E")
                       print substr($1,2) >> /home/$USER/definitivo.txt
               else
                      print substr($1,1,length($1)-1) >> /home/$USER/definitivo.txt
               }'`

Comment: @SergioChuky he editado la respuesta para incluir el redireccionamiento

Comment: awk no es un comando! es un lenguaje :D

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' a ver si así está mejor

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @ordago ahora si que funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias Crack :D

Comment: También puedes expresarlo de forma más idiomática con un `awk '/^E/ {print substr($0, 2); next} {print substr($0, 1, 3)}`.

Answer (score 2):

Díselo a sed, que permite ponerlo de forma bastante claro:

```
$ sed -r '/^E/s/^.(...).*/\1/;s/^([^E]..).*/\1/' fichero
A39
A60
D18
D18
E67
E75
E75
A97
```

Esto es:

```
sed -r '/^E/s/^.(...).*/\1/;s/^([^E]..).*/\1/'
#        ^^   ^^^^^^^^^ ^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- `sed 'una cosa; otra cosa'` para hacer más de una cosa cada vez.
- `-r` para tener sed extendido.
- `/^E/s/^.(...).*/\1/` si la línea empieza por "E", imprime del carácter 2.º al 4.º. ¿Cómo? Cogiendo el texto que queremos volver a imprimir con `(........)` e imprimiéndolo después con `\1`.
- `s/^([^E]..).*/\1/` en caso contrario, imprime los tres primeros caracteres.

---

Alternativamente, y cogiendo la idea de `substr()` de la [respuesta de ordago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326377/83), podríamos decir:

```
awk '/^E/ {print substr($0, 2); next} {print substr($0, 1, 3)}
```

Comment: 37 caracteres, esta valdría para un code golf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :D